# Crypter in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I'm making Crypter from [this tutorial](http://postimg.org/image/lhe1fp3e1/), but I can not compile it - 4 Errors.

First error:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(saveFile, System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(originalStubContents & "@splitter@" & XOR("passphrase", originalFileContents)), False)
```

Description: Expression expected (underlined XOR)

Second error:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(saveFile, System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(originalStubContents & "@splitter@" & XOR("passphrase", originalFileContents)), False)
```

Description: End of statement expected (underlined False)

Third error:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath & "temp1928.exe", Encoding.Default.GetBytes(XOR("passphrase", originalContents)), false)
```

Desciption: Expression expected (underlined XOR)

Last - Fourth Error:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath & "temp1928.exe", Encoding.Default.GetBytes(XOR("passphrase", originalContents)), false)
```

Description: End of statement expected (underlined false)

Can you help me?
If you can not fix the errors from my description, you can download my project [here](http://www84.zippyshare.com/v/S4mgqREi/file.html).

Comment: I don't think [XOR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/csw1x2a6.aspx) does what you think it should do.

Comment: @the_lotus - XOR is used in tutorial and I don't want change algoritm. I will change algorithm when application works with XOR

Comment: I don't have access to your links, I assume they aren't in VB since XOR is a reserved word. If you look at the link I posted, XOR isn't a function that take 2 strings as a parameter.

Comment: @user4653508 Look further down the tutorial - it defines an XOR function which the code snippets you show need. It seems the tutorial got some things out of order.

Comment: @Andrew Morton - could you fix it?

Comment: @user4653508 All you should need to do is add in that function for it to be able to build.